# Using Custom IHttpActionInvoker in WebAPI for TransactionScope in Async actions

Tags: c#, azure, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, transactionscope

I want to apply TransactionScope for every async controller actions. Rather than doing it in every action I want to do it in a central place so that it would be applicable for all actions. I tried creating a custom IHttpActionInvoker which inherits from ApiControllerActionInvoker

```
public class ControllerActionTransactionInvoker : ApiControllerActionInvoker
{
    public override Task<HttpResponseMessage> InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            Task<HttpResponseMessage> result;

            result = base.InvokeActionAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);

            scope.Complete();

            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

then in the Startup class of Web Api replaced default IHttpActionInvoker with the newly created one

```
config.Services.Replace(typeof(IHttpActionInvoker), new ControllerActionTransactionInvoker());
```

Now, I can call a controller action and get result but I manually raised exceptions for a series of Db operations and the desired Transaction process does not work. So there is partial work done in DB.
And it does not work at all after hosting the api in Azure api app. It says the controller action was not found.

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scope` is completing and being disposed before the controller action is finished executing, as you do not await the response.  Try it like this instead:

```
public class ControllerActionTransactionInvoker : ApiControllerActionInvoker
{
    public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> InvokeActionAsync(HttpActionContext actionContext, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled))
        {
            HttpResponseMessage result = await base.InvokeActionAsync(actionContext, cancellationToken);
            scope.Complete();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

While this might well work, you might also want to consider doing this higher up the Web API stack - perhaps in a handler - as you might miss other transactional activity in e.g. handlers, filters, etc.  Depends on what you want in and out of scope.

Comment: Hi, this works locally. I'll check in Azure also later. Thanks a lot!